# What is the handler of an exception raised in constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, try-catch

I am new to C++ exception handling. The rule in my mind is that,

1. If no handler of an exception is found in the **call chain** (the stack of function calling), then the ***terminate*** function is called.
2. A handler is a **catch {}** block.

However, I cannot understand the behaviour of the following.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
using namespace std;

struct X {
  X() try { throw exception(); }
  catch (exception &e) {
    cout << "Exception caught in constructor!" << endl;
  }
};

int main() {

  try {
    throw exception();
  }
  catch (exception &e) {
    cout << "Exception caught in function." << endl;
  }
  cout << "After Exception being caught in function" << endl;

  try {
    X x;
  }
  catch (exception &e) {
    cout << "Why exception is caught again!" << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The output is

`Exception caught in function.
After Exception being caught in function
Exception caught in constructor!
Why exception is caught again!`

**Question 1:** It seems that the exception thrown in the constructor of X is caught (or. handled) twice. Or why the catch{} block following the constructor not counted as a handler for the exception in the constructor?

If I do not put `X x;` in the `try{}` block and catch it in the `main()`, the output is:

`Exception caught in function.
After Exception being caught in function
Exception caught in constructor!
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::exception'
   what():  std::exception
Aborted (core dumped)`

**Question 2:** Is the default terminate() function called when we do not have `X x;` in a try block?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19687623/952747

Comment: @MM. Thanks a lot. I searched but missed that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **have** two exceptions.

```
struct X {
  X() try { throw exception(); }
  catch (exception &e) {
    cout << "Exception caught in constructor!" << endl;
  }
};
```

After an exception you will handle it in the constructor. **BUT** you didn't construct
the object yet and you have no object in the caller's side. The caller
should handle an un-constructed object situation. [<sup>†</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19687623/952747)

Second question, yes. Per *[except.terminate]* in the standard. It causes to invoke `std::terminate`.

Comment: Could you help me on a following question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23753821/why-do-we-need-a-function-try-block.  In an answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19687146/an-exception-gets-thrown-twice-from-a-constructor-with-a-function-try-block/19687623#19687623, user Kerrek SB says "Do not use function-try-blocks, ever."

Answer (score 4):

With:

```
X() try { throw exception(); }
catch (exception &e) {
    cout << "Exception caught in constructor!" << endl;
}
```

`X` object is not completely constructed and so the catch cannot ignore the exception and should re-throw it.

IMO, it is more clear when `X` has a member which throw... (`X() try : member(0) {} catch(exception&) {}` ).

Note that you may use a *normal* try catch inside the constructor block:

```
X() {
    try { throw exception(); }
    catch (exception &e) {
        cout << "Exception caught in constructor!" << endl;
    }
}
```

which is more natural.

Comment: In my personal opinion, when a base class constructor throws is a more better example. One could argue, that you can recover in case of failed member initialization, but not from incomplete initialization of the object.